# How to prove $\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}}=\frac{\frac1x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I would like to prove the following equality $$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}}=\frac{\frac1x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

It is tempting to square both sides of the equation and it is not hard to verify that they are equal. Then, I realized that by squaring the equation I may have altered the original equality and the proof is not really valid.

How do I then show properly that the equation holds?

Comment: The left-hand side is always nonnegative, so there must be some unmentioned constraint on $x$ for the right-hand side to also be nonnegative. If you can ensure both sides are nonnegative, then squaring both sides of the equation is fine since $x \mapsto x^2$ is an invertible map on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Be careful about the direction that a proof goes in.   It should start from a statement known to be true and proceed to arrive at your desired identity by reasoning steps that have a justification.  Also (as @angryavian noted) be careful about the domain of $x$ for which the identity is supposed to be proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check equality of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}}=\frac{\frac1x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we must first determine the range of validity.

**Left-hand side:**

- We have to exclude $x\in\{0,1\}$ otherwise the denominator $x^3-x^2$ is zero. Since the radicand
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}=\frac{x+1}{x^2\left(x-1\right)}
  \end{align*}
  has to be non-negative we consider
  \begin{align*}
  x-1>0,\quad &x+1\geq 0\quad\to\quad x>1\\
  x-1<0,\quad &x+1\leq 0\quad\to\quad x\leq -1
  \end{align*}
  and conclude the left-hand side is valid for $\color{blue}{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus(-1,1]}$.

**Right-hand side:**

- We have to exclude $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$ otherwise a denominator is zero. Since the radicand $x^2-1$ has to be non-negative we consider
  \begin{align*}
  x^2-1>0\quad\to\quad x^2>1\\
  \end{align*}
  and conclude the left-hand side is valid for $\color{blue}{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]}$.

**Region of validity:**

We see the left-hand side of (1) is valid for $x=-1$, leading to zero, while the right-hand side is *undefined* in case $x=-1$. The region of validity is the intersection of the regions from both sides which is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Equality check:**

> We can now check for equality within the range of validity (2). We start with the right-hand side of (1) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{\frac{1}{x}+1}{x^2-1}}&=\frac{1}{x}\,\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{|x|}\,\frac{|x+1|}{\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}}\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{|x|}\,\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}}\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{|x|}\,\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}\\
> &=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^2(x-1)}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we use $\frac{x+1}{x}=\frac{|x+1|}{|x|}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$.
- In (3.2) we use the identity $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: Appreciate the in-depth analysis, which is more than what I initially considered

Comment: @Ace: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $x$ in the LHS: $$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x^3-x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac1x}{x^2-x}}$$Multiply by $\sqrt{1+\frac1x}$ on top and bottom: $$\frac{1+\frac1x}{\sqrt{\left(1+\frac1x\right)\left(x^2-x\right)}}=\frac{1+\frac1x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

since you're manipulating both sides and don't want to square you can multiply both sides by $\sqrt{ x^2 - 1 }$